# responsive embedded youtube

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a responsive youtube video on my website. I need it to look good on desktop and mobile.
this is the code I try:

```css
.iframe-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}
.iframe-container iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <!--Gallery section-->
    <section id="songs" class="gallery main brd-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>נזילה בגוף - מוראס (אודיו)</h1>
            <div class="iframe-container">
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/krhum9lNoXw"
                        frameborder="0"
                        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                        allowfullscreen>
                </iframe>
                <h1 class="large list-inline-item">
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krhum9lNoXw"
                       class="hover-effect"><i class="icon-youtube"></i> </a>
                </h1>
                <h1 class="large list-inline-item">
                    <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/3YX6pjxMfcQ1r2yPJaxpBi"
                       class="hover-effect"><i class="icon-spotify"></i> </a>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <!--End song-->
        </div>
        <!-- End container -->
    </section>
    <!--End gallery section-->
```

This is how it's currently looking at my website:
[image: video not responsive]
I'm new to CSS and HTML so if I forgot to upload anything, let me know and I'll add it.
to see the website I'm working on you can check: http://nhrnhr0.pythonanywhere.com/
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setting-the-player-size): you should use the player `setSize` method

If you want this to be done when you resize your page, use the `window.resize` event (as described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event))

In short:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    // make sure the player variable is global or visible in current scope in your code
    player.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); 
}
```